# How Do I Incorporate Models and Controllers In My Node.js App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, model-view-controller

So I am trying to add database functionality to my simple website and it is frustrating me beyond belief. I can use a basic controller but as soon as I incorporate models the confusion starts. If the controller is run on the client side, how the heck do I import my models? I can't use require because it is server-side. Yet everywhere I look online they simply use require in the controllers.. Where do I store my models and controllers and how do I properly incorporate them into my views? What I've come to hypothesize is the models and controllers must be used server-side somehow and then the information transferred to the view. I must be missing a big concept here if it is this much of a mess. I have a horrible understanding of how all these parts interact and I feel like it is caused by huge gaps in my knowledge of this stuff. And if anyone could link a good resource to better understand the fundamentals of this stuff so I stop making these stupid and frustrating mistakes I'd really appreciate it :) Thank you guys and gals very much

Model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    imgUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    uploadDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    lastUpdated: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    }
});

PostSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
    var currentDate = new Date();

    if(!this.uploadDate) {
        this.uploadDate = currentDate;
    }

    this.lastUpdated = currentDate;

    next();

});

var Post = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);

module.exports = Post;
```

Views:

head.jade:

```
//- CSS
link(href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet")
link(href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet")

//- Scripts
script(src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js")
script(src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js")
script(src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js")
script(src="app/app.js")

title #{title} | Vagablog
```

layout.jade:

```
doctype html
html(ng-app="app")
    head
        include head.jade
        block scripts

    body
        .container-fluid
            .row
                .col-xs-12
                    #logo-container
                        img(class="img-responsive" id="logo" src="../images/logo.png")
            include nav.jade
            block content
            block footer
```

index.jade:

```
extends partials/layout

block scripts
    script(src="app/controllers/PostCtrl.js")

block content
    div(ng-controller="PostCtrl")
        .row
            .col-xs-9
                #main
                    .row
                        .col-xs-12
                            form(class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="post(title, content, image)")
                                .form-group
                                    label(for="inputTitle" class="col-sm-2 control-label") Title
                                    .col-sm-10
                                        input(required type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTitle" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title")
                                .form-group
                                    label(for="inputContent" class="col-sm-2 control-label") Content
                                    .col-sm-10
                                        textarea(required class="form-control" id="inputContent" placeholder="Content" ng-model="content")
                                .form-group
                                    label(for="inputImg" class="col-sm-2 control-label") Image URL
                                    .col-sm-10
                                        input(required type="text" class="form-control" id="inputImg" placeholder="Image URL" ng-model="image")
                                .form-group
                                    .col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-10
                                        button(type="submit" class="btn btn-default") Post

                    .row
                        .col-xs-12
                            div(ng-repeat="post in getPosts()")
                                hr
                                .well
                                    h2 {{ post.title }}
                                    h4 {{ post.content }}
                                    img(src="{{ post.imgUrl }}")
                                    p Uploaded: {{ post.uploadDate }}
                                    p Last Updated: {{ post.lastUpdated }}

            .col-xs-3
                .row
                    .col-xs-12
                        #sidebar
                            .well(style="height: 500px;")

block footer
    .row
        .col-xs-12
            hr
            .footer
                h4(class="copyright") Footer
```

Controller:

```
(function() {

    var Post = require("../models/post");

    var PostCtrl = function ($scope, $log, $location) {

        $scope.post = function (postTitle, postContent, postImage) {

            var newPost = Post({
                title: postTitle,
                content: postContent,
                imgUrl: postImage,
                uploadDate: new Date(),
            });

            newPost.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                };
            });

        };

        $scope.getPosts = function() {

            Post.find({}, function(err, posts) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                };

                return posts;

            });

        };
    };

    app.controller("PostCtrl", ["$scope", "$log", "$location", PostCtrl]);

})();
```

The Many Errors:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
 PostCtrl.js:3:6

"Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/ng/areq?p0=PostCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

GET 
http://localhost:3000/%7B%7B%20post.imgUrl%20%7D%7D  [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 4ms]
```

Comment: You're mixing client and server-side code. Mongoose cannot be run in the browser. Nor can you use `require` in the browser without a compiler. You'' have to use a node http server such as express to create an api that you can access in your angular controller

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Any resources that reference this or example projects?

Comment: any MEAN stack project seed will show you the separation mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're running into is mixing client and server code. What you're going to want to do is create an API which exposes routes that your client side app can access. These routes will return mongoose queries.

This [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4) should offer everything you need to setup the API server

Regarding your client code, you'll want to create factories with angular which have functions for each respective endpoint. Within those functions, you can leverage the `$http` service to read and mutate data from the resources. This can be done like so:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('bearsFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
  var urlBase = 'localhost:9000/api/bears';

  return {
    getBears: function () {
      return $http.get(urlBase);
    },

    getBear: function (id) {
      return $http.get(urlBase + '/' + id);
    },

    createBear: function (bear) {
      return $http.post(urlBase, bear);
    },

    updateBear: function (bear) {
      return $http.put(urlBase + '/' + bear.ID, bear)
    },

    deleteBear: function (id) {
      return $http.delete(urlBase + '/' + id);
    }
  }
}]);
```

Then in your controllers you can leverage these factories like so:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('bearController', ['$scope', 'bearsFactory', function ($scope, bearsFactory) {
  $scope.getBears() {
    bearsFactory.getBears()
    .success(function (bears) {
      $scope.bears = bears;
    })
    .error(function (error) {
      $scope.status = 'Unable to load bear data: ' + error.message;
    });
  }
}]);
```